# Is there a way to replicate mysql_result using mysqli (procedural)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using mysqli instead of mysql, and came across the error `Call to undefined function mysqli_result()`

From looking on Google, the general consensus is that mysql_result was a useless function anyway and there is no need for it in the MySQLi library. However, I think it is useful and can't see what's wrong with the following code?

```
do
{
    $id = rand_id();
    $exists = mysql_query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `files` WHERE `name` = "' . $id . '")');
}
while (mysql_result($exists, 0) === 1);
```

Is there a way to replicate the way mysql_result worked without changing the code too much?

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a debate topic.

Comment: you're right. I've edited it

Comment: sorry guys, should have found those before. I've flagged it as a duplicate. thanks

Comment: Some questions under PHP tag just drive me crazy. "How to use some bad practice to make bad code work?"

Comment: @YourCommonSense some comments on SO just drive me crazy. "Your code is bad" with no explanation as to what's bad about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement it yourself,

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
    $res->data_seek($row); 
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```

`mysql_result`'s popularity came from people who only needed to access a single row or field. As of PHP 5.4, [array dereferencing support](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) has now been added, so you can do:

```
$result->fetch_assoc()['field'];
```

So in your example, you could instead do

```
while ($exists->fetchassoc()[0] === 1);
```

Comment: thanks, `while (mysqli_fetch_assoc($exists)[0] === 1);` worked perfectly.

Comment: the only mysql_result's popularity came from tutorials written in the last century. @cantsay you better learn some not *that old* practice instead of trying to use it with new API

Answer (score -1):

In this specific instance, you could use:

```
do {
    $id = rand_id();
    $exists = mysqli_query("SELECT 1 FROM files WHERE name = $id");
} while (mysqli_num_rows($exists));
```

As for other instances where you may want to use `mysql_result`, the documentation suggests:

> - `mysqli_data_seek()` in conjunction with `mysqli_field_seek()` and `mysqli_fetch_field()`
> - `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`

Cycling through to an arbitrary row in PHP may be confusing.  I think it would make more sense to use `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` in the query itself.